# Rotation with perspective jumps in Firefox 32.0.1

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I'm transforming a div with perspective(150px) and rotateY(-1deg) and on hover I'm transitioning the rotation to 0deg.

Everything worked great, on Firefox 31.0 for Windows, then I updated to Firefox 32.0.1.

Now in Firefox 32.0.1, the perspective and rotation work, but the transition between the normal state and the hover state has a nasty little jump that I can't seem to get rid of.

Here's the stripped down code:

```css
#wrap {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    width:550px;
}
#one, #two {
    height:100px;
    width:550px;
    background:red;
    margin: 50px 0;
    transition:all 1s linear;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#one {
    text-align:right;
    transform-origin: left center 0px;
    transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(1deg);
}
#two {
    transform-origin: right center 0px;
    transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(-1deg);
}
#one:hover, #two:hover {
    transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(0deg);
    transition:all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m2qjy2ka/4/)**

To recreate the issue, hover on the red divs and watch the right edge. At the end of the transition you will see a 5-10 pixel shift/jump.

I've tried:

- Moving perspective to the parent element.
- `backface-visibility: hidden;` and other anti-aliasing methods
- Using `rotate3D()` rather than `rotateY()`
- Using `transform-style: preserve-3d;`
- Various combinations of perspective and rotation*

*Using more extreme perspective values seems to reduce the appearance of the jump, but strangely if I hover over the elements several times in succession the jump comes and goes randomly. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m2qjy2ka/7/)

Note that the problem doesn't appear in other browsers/versions.

Comment: A curiosity: [this codepen](http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/kiajB) (linked from another SO answer) suffers of the same exact problem in Firefox, while it works in Chrome.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Webkit browsers seem to be able to handle these fairly well, strangely even IE can handle my simple use case. Any thoughts on a workaround?

Comment: Nope. Btw in the related SO question, this little firefox problem isn't even mentioned, and instead the big problems occour with Safari :| I think it's still a jungle out there, browsers need some time to fix this mess

Comment: @AndreaLigios If you're on the cutting edge you're going to bleed a little...

Comment: problem fixed in firefox v34! but this time there is a lag while rotating. in previous versions that the bug wasn't there the lag wasn't either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a look at the issue, and you are right about the differences between the firefox versions.

The problem is the `0deg` value in the rotate transformation. I've tried two different solutions, one of which seems to work every time on testing, and the other glitches occasionally.

My solution using `0rad` is the occasional glitchy solution:

```css
#wrap {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 550px;
}

#one, #two {
  height: 100px;
  width: 550px;
  background: red;
  margin: 50px 0;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#one {
  left: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  transform-origin: left center 0px;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(0.05rad);
}


#one:hover {
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(0rad);
}


#two {
  right: 1px;
  transform-origin: right center 0px;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(-0.05rad);
}


#two:hover {
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(0rad);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

My other solution requires a bit more work with positions and size to give the perception of a `0deg` transform by using a value of `0.1deg`.

```css
#wrap {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 550px;
}

#one, #two {
  height: 100px;
  width: 550px;
  background: red;
  margin: 50px 0;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#one {
  left: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  transform-origin: left center 0px;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(1deg);
}

#two {
  right: 1px;
  transform-origin: right center 0px;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(-1deg);
}

#one:hover {
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(0.1deg);
  width: 552px;
}

#two:hover {
  right: 3px;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(-0.1deg);
  width: 552px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

Ultimately the differences in the two solutions is the amount of work required to get it to work.
For the occasional glitch, I would suffice with `rad` over `deg`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've just tested the fiddle in fullscreen and it's a lot more stable than I have given it credit for

Comment: Your second solution looks promising

Comment: A lot of the supposed improvement appears to come from you using a faster transition period (0.5s) vs the original (1s).  Please adjust your examples to a transition of 1s so that they can be directly compared. When making things for human-perception based comparisons please keep as much as possible the same. [Adjusting yours to 1s, to the original size, and putting all 3 versions on one page at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jo1crzhd/2/) I see no significant improvement on my machine testing on all of Firefox 28.0, 31.0, 32.0.2, 33.0b5 (beta), and 34.0a2 (alpha).

Comment: I am not "stepping" on his solutions. I would *never* do so. I am merely reporting what I see *on my machine* after adjusting them so I could compare them on the same page & same trans time. I would never put out that effort (and testing in 5 different versions of Firefox) without reporting what I *actually* observe. Our prior comments make clear people see different things based on their OS/HW config. If you don't want that feedback, I am happy to not spend the time. In the absence of a *fix*, I thought the goal was as good a solution as possible. Input from multiple people helps that.

Comment: @apaul34208: In the JSFiddle you linked above I see no significant difference (FF32.0.2 and FF34.0a2) between the cases on the page with respect to movement. Variation in actual performance can make any of them better depending on the trial run. The only significant difference is that for the one marked "Terry Barriff's 2nd test case (1s)" the top `<div>` never reaches the right edge of the containing `<div>`. All of the right aligned `<div>`s significantly jump around on the right edge.

Comment: You're right, works computer seemed to show it a lot smoother. I have fired up the Windows 8 VM running FF 32 and it's dreadful. For what it's worth, it looks amazing on FF32 on Mac now.

Comment: adding the following to tb2 resolves the divs reaching the edge issue:


`#one-tb2:hover {
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(0.1deg);
    width:908px
}

#two-tb2:hover {
  right: 9px;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(-0.1deg);
  width: 908px;
}`

Comment: Running it on Windows 8.1 on my Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Series laptop with the core i7 processor looks really nice... Perhaps this issue has a lot more to do with running environment than I thought.

Comment: @apaul34208 definitely, ff on the mac is perfect with solution 2

Comment: @TerryBarriff & @apaul34208: In the environments where it is looking good, can you try it with another process(es) providing some load to the CPU(s)? This might give an indication as to if the problem you see --it appears I primarily see a different problem-- is more OS/HW related or more related to how FF chooses to drop frames when it instantaneously predicts there will not be enough CPU to render the next frame(s) needed for the animation to be smooth. Even if so, that still does not excuse the jumping around of the right side of the right-aligned `<div>` which I see.

Comment: you have set `width` to some element. this not fare. this is cheating. user [Terry Barriff][http://stackoverflow.com/users/639230/terry-barriff]

Comment: @Makyen I can assign more or less cores to the vm, as well as the amount of GPU power in order to test this. That said, I think you are correct in saying that it is hardware related. Incidentally, what are your hardware specs?

Comment: @TerryBarriff: A good colloquial description for the machine I am using would be old and relatively slow, running XP. On the other hand, it is sufficiently fast to permit the CPU to render 720p video w/o assist from the GPU. I can see if I can bring up another machine here which is faster, but it has been having some issues. I am willing to share the exact config, but being an advocate for privacy, I would prefer to do so in some way which is more private than posting to a public location.

Comment: @apaul34208: [Assuming you are going to award the bounty.]: Of the two of us, give the bounty to Terry Barriff. From what you have said, the workaround provided here got you closer to a more convenient easing of the issues you see on your machine than my masking the left and right edges.

Comment: @Makyen While your masking looks better in the given example, in my actual use case the divs contain images so masking isn't really an option. Thanks again for all the time and effort you put into this though you definitely get a +1 from me.

Comment: @apaul34208: Thanks. No problem. I must admit I had assumed this was a simplified case and that masking would be... inconvenient. TerryBarriff: +1 from me.

Comment: @apaul34208: FYI: Awarding the bounty is a [separate step](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) from accepting the answer. I don't think you desire to let it just expire.  If you do, only half of the bounty will be awarded, and I might be the one to get it (same vote count with my answer entered first).

Comment: @apaul34208: I might be reading it wrong, but the page [I linked](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) says the bounty is *not* automatically awarded to an accepted answer: "You can accept an answer without awarding a bounty to it." If awarding the bounty at the end of the grace period to the accepted answer was automatic, then that statement would be false. It also states:"If you do not award the bounty [by the end of the grace period], half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, [with a] score of at least 2."

Answer (score 2):

From what version did you update? I have tried Firefox 28.0, 31.0, 32.0.2, 33.0b4 (beta), 33.0b5 (beta), and 34.0a2 (alpha).  All experience this issue.

After trying multiple possibilities for property values, my belief is that this is a bug in the rendering engine. While it might be possible to find some combination of properties that forces the rendering engine to be referenced to the right, using `transform-origin: right center 0px;` (as you have) does appear to be what should cause this to be locked to the right edge.

The correct action appears to be to [file a bug with Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi).

Here is a screen capture of the jump I see into the `<div>`:
[image]

And out of the `<div>` (only a couple of pixels):
[image: out of the div on the right]

Looking at it some more, the bottom `<div>` also jumps in the vertical direction.

As mentioned, it is unlikely there will be a workaround. However, I can suggest a hack which actually makes a dramatic improvement (at least for me).

The hack is to obscure the edges which are where the issues show up. It is not really a good solution.  However, for these simple mono colored divs it does look better.  [**Here is a JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kg0355yg/5/) you can test with (definitely not as compete as you would need, but it will give you an idea).

```css
html, body, * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#mak-overwrap {
    border: 0px solid #000;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    width:590px;
    pointer-events:none;
}
#mak-wrap1 {
    border: 0px solid #000;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    width:570px;
    left:10px;
    pointer-events:none;
}
#mak-wrap2 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    width:550px;
    left:10px;
    top:0px;
    height:400px;
    background:transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
}
#mak-three {
    height:300px;
    width:20px;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:10;
    background:white;
    top:30px;
}
#mak-four {
    height:300px;
    width:20px;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:572px;
    z-index:10;
    background:white;
    top:30px;
}
#mak-one-in {
    height:50px;
    width:75px;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    z-index:11;
    background:transparent;
    top:0px;
    left:218px
}
#mak-two-in {
    height:50px;
    width:75px;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    z-index:11;
    background:transparent;
    top:0px;
    left:274px
}
#mak-one, #mak-two {
    height:100px;
    width:570px;
    background:red;
    margin: 50px 0;
    transition:all 1s linear;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    position: reletive;
    z-index:2;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
#mak-one {
    text-align:right;
    transform-origin: left center 0px;
    transform: perspective(120.7px) rotateY(1deg);
    left:0px;
}
#mak-two {
    transform-origin: right center 0px;
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(-1deg);
    left:0px;
}
#mak-one:hover, #mak-two:hover {
    transform: perspective(150px) rotateY(0deg);
    transition:all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="mak-overwrap">
    <div id="mak-wrap1">
        <div id="mak-one">
            <div id="mak-one-in">one</div>
        </div>
        <div id="mak-two">
            <div id="mak-two-in">two</div>
        </div>
        <div id="mak-wrap2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="mak-three"></div>
    <div id="mak-four"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just downgraded to be sure I wasn't just loosing it... I was on Firefox 31.0 on both Windows 8 and Windows 7. Already filed a bug report, still looking for a workaround to get things working while they debug.

Comment: [Check this screen capture of the sans-shifty behavior on Firefox 31.0](http://youtu.be/NpXvtZfUi4w)

Comment: With all the versions I mentioned, running on XP, I see the bottom div jump on the right side throughout the transition both into and out of hover. I tired it with and without hardware acceleration enabled. The jumps are mostly towards the left (into the div), but also to the right (out of the div). Jumps out of the div are usually small (few pixels). Jumps into the div are quite noticeable. Unfortunately, this is not the type of error for which there is often a workaround. Thanks for filing the bug. Many people don't take that step.

Comment: Sorry about the comment yesterday, I interpreted your comment as being competitive when you were just pointing out a potential problem. Thanks for the time and effort you've put in to this so far.

Comment: No problem. While the bounty did draw my attention to this question (The question was too old. It would not have hit my radar without the bounty), *solving problems* has always been my motivator, not the reward for doing so. Once it was clear that a *fix* is unlikely, it became a question of exploring possibilities to give you information so you can get functionality that is closer to what you desire.